# Regex in C - pattern matches too early and drops trailing character(s)

Tags: c, regex

I'm working on an interpolation module in C. I have access to both POSIX and PCRE2 regex parsers. Essentially, I have a block of text which contains tokens. These tokens are substituted with values from a lookup table. Each token has the ability to specify alternate text if said token is not found in the lookup table.

Nominally, a token is formatted as `?{token}`  To handle situations where a token may not be defined and you want alternate text, you suffix the token with a ':' (color) and the alternate, thusly `?{token:alternate}`  The alternate can be plain text or another token.

The module has the ability to process nested tokens; this includes a token as alternate text. Such a definition looks like `?{token:?{alt_token}}`  And herein lies the problem. When I parse this, I get `?{token:?{alt_token}` as the match. Notice that the closing '}' is missing. When I un-greedy the pattern where it captures the alternate text, the regex over-grabs.

A pathological example would be `?{some:?{deep:?{replacement:?{inside:all this}}}}` Ideally, this would grab and resolve (on each pass) the following:

- `?{inside:all this}`
- `?{replacement:?{inside:all this}}`
- `?{deep:?{replacement:?{inside:all this}}}`
- `?{some:?{deep:?{replacement:?{inside:all this}}}}`

... but what I get is each one missing its closing '}'

I'm using several capture groups in my regex to group/grab the token and its optional alternate text. Here's my regex:

```
`"\\Q?{\\E([\\Q:=\\E]{0,1}[A-Za-z_-][0-9A-Za-z_\\.-]*?)(\\:(.*?)){0,1}\\Q}\\E"`
```

`match[0]` is the whole RE; `match[1]` is the token; `match[3]` is the alternate text

Any suggestions how I might modify my regex to retain the closing '}' when the token to parse ends with more than one '}' ... ?

Comment: If you use PCRE, you may use  `\?\{[:=]?[-.\w]+(?::(?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)?\}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/x7rbQD/1)

Comment: If you are after groups, you may use something like https://regex101.com/r/x7rbQD/2, but you won't have access to the nested groups. Unless there is a way to access a group stack in PCRE2.

Comment: TY @WiktorStribiżew for the insights; I've learned a bit. After poking at this for days with no luck, I'm fairly convinced that regex can't do what I need. I have, however, found a non-regex solution. I didn't post an "answer" as it's not an answer, per se.